# Validating a connect 4 board state

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

All connect 4 states aren't possible. For instance, the number of token of each color should be equal or at most only one should be missing for either color.

Discussing with a colleague, he told me to simply try to "unstack" them.

I saw somewhere a document stating that it was more complex than that.

Has one the reference I am looking for ?

Details :

A board is given and some token are already in. We know that white/red started and try to decide if the configuration is valid.

Comment: What is exactly your question and what do you want try to solve?

Comment: Ok I think I understand the problem now. I guess unstacking should work fine in combination with some brute force algorithm. Just take back one token at a time alternating red and white. If you can get to the begin state like this, than your board was valid.

Comment: Indeed one can approach it as a "shortest" path problem, somewhat more efficiently done by going "backward" from the given state to the initial state of a Connect 4 board.